# Package design and implementation

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, package

I'm not completely new to Python, but my main training is in Java. The differences between Java and Python (for instance, the OOP philosophies, error handling, etc) are mostly what I'm not familiar with.

#### The Problem

For an internship, I'm trying to develop a structured data parser. I'm aware of existing frameworks like BeautifulSoup, xml, and lxml. Despite these, I would like to build one specifically to orient myself around package design, philosophy, and organization.

One thing that's important to me is the semantics of importing. I want to be able to call upon the parser like this (where the package name is `pyrse`).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pyrse import parse
from pyrse import write
# Two imports so new users understand the divergent functionality

fd = open("/path/to/my/data.xml")
data1 = parse.xml.from.file(fd)
print(write.json.to.string(data1))

str = "<test>dummy xml data</test>"
data2 = parse.xml.from.string(str)
print(write.markdown.to.string(data2))
```

I know the examples are a *little* out there but I want to extend this in the future. For now, I just want to understand how I should be building this on my filesystem.

So far, he's how I *think* I want this to be structured, in order to get the same structure as used above:

```
pyrse/
    _dev/
        tests/
        data/
            __init__.py
            element.py
    parse/
        xml/
            __init__.py
            file.py
            string.py
            stream.py
        html/
            __init__.py
            file.py
    write/
        xml/
            __init__.py
            file.py
            string.py
        json/
            __init__.py
            file.py
```

To be entirely clear on the diagram above:

- `_dev` is a weakly hidden folder for developer use. The client shouldn't be importing this folder, from which the parsers and writers will inherit the base class, Element, for their own data trees. Philosophically similar to `lxml`'s `etree`.
- `parse` is obviously the package in which a structured data reader will reside. Divided by language, these folders then divide by target input or output method. Hopefully, this structure is both intuitive for developers and clients of the package.
- I have no idea how to make the `from` work in the package design (short of putting all the stuff in its own subfolder, which seems clunky, unless that's the only way). Maybe `from` doesn't even need to be there-- but I'm not sure which would be more semantic to a Python user-- `parse.xml.file()` or `parse.xml.from.file()`?

To summarize the whole thing, I am very flexible on how this would work. I really want:

- Intuitive, semantic importing
- Preferably intuitive file layout
- Therefore extensible/modular development scheme

Beyond this, all I have is ideas and vaporware. If I'm wrong in how I've started planning, I definitely want to know.

Thanks to anyone who thinks they can help!

#### Additional Information

- I'm using Python 3.3.2, and I'm hoping to keep this compatible to the 3.x family.
- I have no actual idea what I'm doing here. I might have an idea in Java, but the approach that Python (and PEP8) would take is far different, so even what I'm hoping to do would be difficult.
- I'm designing to be extensive, so people can write  parser and  writers independently of one another.
- The `pyrse` project can be found on [GitHub](http://www.github.com/jwarner112/pyrse) for anyone who is interested in helping, or things that this might make more sense in context. Virtually no work has been put in yet, as I'm trying to handle this whole design problem ahead of time.
- My project is licensed with the Unlicense, so go hog-wild if you're personally interested in this. I'm just hoping it's useful to someone (myself included) some day, and that I learn from it.

#### Revisions

1. So [mescalinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1044117/mescalinum) made an excellent point with [What Color Should the Bikeshed Be?](https://wiki.hackerspaces.org/The_Bikeshed_Anti-Pattern), and I realize that I'm asking a subtly wrong question that's distracting me from my project rather than helping me plan it. I'm more interested in the divide between package and filesystem; Packages and imports provide a layer of abstraction from the filesystem beneath it and **that** confuses me. What are the implications on a filesystem of doing `import pyrse` and calling `pyrse.parse.xml...` versus `import pyrse.parse.xml` and calling `xml.file()`? What should be in a `.py` file, and what should be a folder? How do these affect imports? This question's less organized than the previous one, but more accurate. If need be, I'll open a new question for this one.

Comment: `from` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), you can't use it as part of a module name.

Comment: I'd go for something like `from pyrse.parse import parse_xml_file`, or `from purse.parse.xml import parse_file`. loose that "semantic" module tricks

Comment: @DanielRoseman Even in the `word.from.word` context? I assumed it would know how to handle the whitespace.

Comment: @mescalinum This may venture more into discussion and philosophy, but what makes you favor that over my approach? Assuming you're more experienced with Python than I am, what makes this more intuitive to you?

Comment: It's not intuitiveness. But what you propose is quite atypical compared to other python packages. Anyway, there is no formal rule, so it's a matter of taste. Slightly related: [What colour the bike shed should be?](https://wiki.hackerspaces.org/The_Bikeshed_Anti-Pattern)

Comment: @mescalinum Thanks so much for that link, anti-patterns describe about 100% of the problems I've had working on my own personal projects. I can't upvote this more than once, but I would it I could.

I'm also updating the question to reflect a minor change on direction based on your feedback.